# Will I receive my SSN automatically by mail?

Tags: visa, immigration, family, social-security

I arrived in the US on July 5th 2020 on an F4 visa. I assume that I don’t have to apply for a Social Security number, considering I have asked to be issued one on the DS-260. If that is indeed the case, how long will it take for me to receive it?